# Wrap an Image on a cylinder with Imagick in PHP

Tags: php, imagick

since some days i'll try to wrap an Image around a Cylinder (later to generate preview pictures of cups with individual pictures) with Imagick and PHP. My current solution is based on the IM documentation: http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/mapping/

```
  convert rose: -background black -gravity south -splice 0x8 \
          \( +clone -sparse-color barycentric '0,0 black 69,0 white' \) \
          \( -clone 1 -function arcsin 0.5 \) \
          \( -clone 1 -level 25%,75% \
                 -function polynomial -4,4,0 -gamma 2 \
                 +level 50%,0 \) \
          -delete 1 \
          -virtual-pixel black  -define compose:args=17x7 \
          -compose Displace  -composite   rose_cylinder.png
```

I'm trying to convert this command in PHP Imagick functions but the result is not what i expected.

Thats my Code:

```
$clondedOriginal = clone $img;
$clondedOriginal->setBackgroundColor("none");
$clondedOriginal->setGravity(Imagick::GRAVITY_SOUTH);

$mapBase = new Imagick();
$mapBase->newPseudoImage($clondedOriginal->getImageWidth(), $clondedOriginal->getImageHeight(), "canvas:white");
$mapBase->sparseColorImage(Imagick::SPARSECOLORMETHOD_BARYCENTRIC, [0, 0,   0, 0, 0, 1,   $mapBase->getImageWidth(), 0,  1, 1, 1, 1]);
$mapBase->writeImage($dir . "/testBase.png");

$xMap = clone $mapBase;
$xMap->functionImage(Imagick::FUNCTION_ARCSIN, [0.5]);
$xMap->writeImage($dir . "/testX.png");

$yMap = clone $mapBase;
$quantumLong = Imagick::getQuantumRange()['quantumRangeLong'];
$yMap->levelImage( 0.25 * $quantumLong, $yMap->getImageGamma(), 0.75 * $quantumLong, Imagick::CHANNEL_ALL);
$yMap->functionImage(Imagick::FUNCTION_POLYNOMIAL, [-4,4,0]);
$yMap->levelImage(0.5 * $quantumLong, $yMap->getImageGamma(), 0);
$yMap->writeImage($dir . "/testY.png");

$clondedOriginal->setImageVirtualPixelMethod(Imagick::VIRTUALPIXELMETHOD_BLACK);
$clondedOriginal->setImageArtifact("compose:args", "200x0");
$clondedOriginal->compositeImage($xMap, Imagick::COMPOSITE_DISPLACE, 0, 0);

$clondedOriginal->setImageVirtualPixelMethod(Imagick::VIRTUALPIXELMETHOD_BLACK);
$clondedOriginal->setImageArtifact("compose:args", "0x200");
$clondedOriginal->compositeImage($yMap, Imagick::COMPOSITE_DISPLACE, 0, 0);

$clondedOriginal->writeImage($dir . "/didit.png");
```

Every step i tried to generate Testimages. Here they are

- [Original Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NsxVC.png)
- [testbase.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W1PNy.png)
- [testX.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PQuFa.png)
- [testY.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XGogx.png)
- [result (didit.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GE4mf.png)

I hope there's somebody who can help me.

Comment: "Warp" or "Wrap"? Two different animals here.

Comment: Mh i think i mean wrap. Sorry my english is really beautiful

Comment: Just wondering, did you ever solve this? I am encountering the same issue with cylinders, the thing is that the PHP level function uses different values then the image magick +level function. I've been trying to figure this out for the entire day now....